# RestAssured Library: Not able to define a retry strategy when test returns http 503

Tags: rest-assured, http-status-code-503, retry-logic

We are currently using rest assured version 5.3.1. for our API testing.
We would like to define a retry strategy for our rest-assured calls when test returns http 503 status code.

Did below changes

```
HttpClientConfig httpClientConfig = HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                                                            .setParam("http.connection.timeout",
                                                                      Duration.ofSeconds(30)
                                                                              .toMillis())
                                                            .setParam("http.socket.timeout",
                                                                      Duration.ofSeconds(30)
                                                                              .toMillis())
                                                            .setParam("http.connection-manager.timeout",
                                                                      Duration.ofSeconds(30)
                                                                              .toMillis())
                                                            .httpClientFactory(() -> HttpClientBuilder
                                                                    .create()
                                                                    .setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(
                                                                            new DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy())
                                                                    .build());

         config = RestAssured.config().httpClient(httpClientConfig);
```

Observed below error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient@af9a89f' with class 'org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient' to class 'org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient'
```

PS: Observed similar issue being reported in older posts. But still would like to know, if we already have a fix or any work around is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The title and body of your question is mismatch? What is your problem? retry logic or casting error.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I am trying to write a retry logic in rest-assured api calls when service returns 503 status code and while doing so, facing above casting error

Comment: You can see the known issue 497 in github. https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/497 Now, there is no way to do that in RA, you have to implement retry logic in client code. While-loop is a choice to go.

Comment: Thanks, had seen that known issue. But as it was an old issue, so wanted to check, if others had done it in a better way. What do yo mean my client code

Comment: Client code is your code. Just use a for-loop or while-loop to check the status of the response and do the retry.